# Show/Download the web service response (blob) as pdf in visualforce page in Salesforce

Tags: web-services, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, apex

I am facing the issue to download/render the blob response in visualforce page with iframe or other alternatives. But i have no luck with any of them. Can any one suggest on this to render/download the blob response as pdf in visualforce page.Got the blob response and parsed it to String as below.

```
    HttpResponse res = http.send(r);
    pdfContent = res.getBodyAsBlob();  //Blob property
    pdf = EncodingUtil.Base64Encode(pdfContent);//String property
```

Below is the visualforce code:

```
         <apex:page doctype="html-5.0" controller="ViewDocument" id="thePage" >

        <apex:outputPanel id="benefit" rendered="{!showDocument}">

            <iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,{!pdf}"  id="theFrame1" width="0%" height ="0%" border="0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"/>

    </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:page>
```

Comment: That looks about right. Check this for an example:https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000044612&language=en_US
Note that this isn't supported in some browsers, like IE8 for sure. There's no way to do this in those, we asked.

Comment: @Egor I am getting same issue ... IS there any workaround for this ? I am getting "Failed to load PDF document."

Comment: Can you suggest/Post the solution for the above issue? Couldn't render PDF blob as data in VF page

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `EncodingUtil.Base64Encode(pdfContent)` try `Blob.toPDF(pdfContent)`.